# Webfaction Mezzanine ALLOWED_HOSTS 200 error

Tags: django, hosts, webfaction, mezzanine

So my site shows up fine with `DEBUG = True`, but I get a 200 server error when I change it to False. I've been reading around and saw that 500 errors are common but I can't find anything on a 200 error. My local_settings.py file doesn't have an ALLOWED_HOSTS area, so I put one in as well as my servers IP address, but still get the same issue. Here's my traceback.

[Thu May 16 16:21:10 2013] [error] /home/cleathers89/.envs/beak_mezz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:48: UserWarning: You haven't defined the ALLOWED_HOSTS settings, which Django 1.5 requires. Will fall back to the domains configured as sites.

I also looked into the conf.py file where it tells me the error is coming from, but I don't think I'm supposed to edit that. I'm a total noob to servers so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` has been been added in the version 1.5 "to prevent an attacker from poisoning caches and password reset emails with links to malicious hosts by submitting requests with a fake HTTP Host header"

Basically you only need to add the name of domains here which will be using the project.

**Example:**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.my-django-project.com', 'your-username.webfaction.com', ]
# ie. not the ip-address but the actual domain name
```

This is used only in production (that is why it shows up only when `DEBUG` is set to `FALSE`). As it is used in production settings, thus you will need to add the above in `production_settings.py` and **not in** `local_settings.py`

Link to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: In addition to this correct answer, with Mezzanine, if this is causing you an error, it's also an indication that you haven't correctly configured a site record in the admin, which you'll need to do.

Comment: In mezzanine, after the above change, I was getting this error: `ImportError: Could not import settings`. I'm not sure what @Stephen was talking about, but for myself with Mezzanine, I had to change line 25 in `manage.py` from `settings_module = "%s.settings" % PROJECT_DIRNAME` to `settings_module = "settings"`. This is because (I believe), Django 1.4/1.5 now works with the `manage.py` file one directory up, while Mezzanine has a flat structure (all files in the base project directory). After that change, everything worked fine.